# how can I open a sqlite file in ios for reading without copying to documents?

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I got an app I'm working on that uses static data from a sqlite database to do various things, While I only need read only access to the database, depending on the episode they pick from the first screen I want it to use a different database file and I want the list of available episodes to be updateable on the fly. and I got help to get the list of available episodes updated, and the proper content downloaded and stored in separate folders, So I know I could when the episode is selected delete the sql file in the documents folder and copy in the new one each time and that would work well enough for what I'm trying to do. but it seems like a bit much extra work to have to check for file, delete file, copy in new one. then open it from there each time the user wants to pick a different episode. and I don't want to put all the sql files together as that will be a bigger hassle then the first route especially if this app stays around long enough to have a long list of episodes.

so my question here is: can I get at least read-only access to an sql file that I've downloaded (or one in the bundle for testing) with out having to first copy it to the documents?  and if so how would i open the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I get at least read-only access to an SQL file that I've downloaded (or one in the bundle for testing) without having to first copy it to the documents directory?

Yes. Files in the app bundle are readable (if they weren't, there would be no point in storing files in the bundle).

> And if so, how would I open the file?

It's not clear what you're asking here - if you want to perform SQL queries on the file, you should use the `sqlite3` library which is available on iOS.

Comment: Even if you manage to open a Sqlite3 DB from within the bundle: what about the journal file and other temp files Sqlite might require? Is it smart enough to place them in a writable folder, or will it just crash?

Comment: @Krumelur That's an implementation detail. If you open a file as read-only, then the implementation must assume it's read-only (exactly for this purpose). Have you never seen an app with a local static database inside?

Comment: I've never seen the code for such an app on ios yet. I was thinking it should be possible but all the tutorials on SQL for iOS I could find all start with either making the database from scratch or copying the file out of the bundle to the documents before doing anything with it, so I wasn't sure. and I want to run sql query's against it, and I don't need to modify the database at all.

Comment: @KitRamos Yes, that's possible, don't be afraid.